# JavaScript how to open new window then change its URL?

Tags: javascript, url, location

```
<script language=JavaScript>
winRef = new Object();
winRef.closed = true;
</script>

<form name=f1 id=f1>
<input type=button name=b1 id=b1 value="New window" 
onClick="winRef=window.open('http://www.google.com/','myNewWindow',
  'left=15,top=15,width=510,height=420,toolbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,status=1');
  winRef.focus()">

<input type=button name=b2 id=b2 value="Close the window" 
onClick="if(!winRef.closed)winRef.close();">

<input type=button name=b3 id=b3 value="Check: is it closed?" 
onClick="alert(winRef.closed ? 'It\'s CLOSED!':'It\'s still OPEN!');">

<input type=button name=b4 id=b4 value="Change new window URL" 
onClick="winRef.location.href('http://example.com/' + winRef.location.href)">
</form>
```

this code opens google in new window then check if its open or not and closes it. How could I change its name to be "http://example.com/?url=http://www.google.com/"
I need to put my site url in front of the open windows URL

Comment: `href` is not a function

Answer (score 1):

here is the code:

```
    <script language="javascript">
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,width=200,height=200";
var nome='nameofme';
 function vamos(url1){
    win = window.open(url1,nome,strWindowFeatures);
    win.focus();
    // If the window opened successfully (e.g: not blocked)
    if (win) {
        win.onload = function() {//onload can be blocked by the brower
            win.location.href='http://www.bing.com';
        };
    }
    setTimeout("win.location.href='http://www.bing.com'",4000);//change the href after 4 second
    win.focus();
    window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', '?http://www.bing.com');
    setTimeout("window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', '?http://www.fava.com')",4000);//after 4 sec
}
</script>
<button id="dd" onClick="vamos('http://www.google.com')">but</button>
```

here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4Sf5/1/) , keep it in mind that, in the fiddle, window.history.replaceState won't works

Comment: thats nice but what I really need is the link after redirect, ex: www.google.com after opening will be redirected to www.google.com.uk so I need the last link after my page link www.example.com/?www.google.com.uk

Comment: @user2443940 You need to redirect the user after time or just when the new window is opened?

Comment: but how to put my link with the present link ?

Comment: @user2443940 Code updated, check it please

Comment: When I open a new window with a window.open() I want to allow the user to change the URL if they want to navigate. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: @SiKni8 you have to add the location bar to the window, this can be made by adding a feature to the function, check it here, it's really simple (first example should help you): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open